# Let $f(x)=x \cdot \sqrt {x-1}$ is $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)$ undefined?

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=x \cdot \sqrt {x-1}$

Normally, do you consider $f(0)=0$ or undefined?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i would argue it is undefined because (without complex numbers) you can't take the squareroot of a negative number. You can not just argue zero times anything is zero if that "anything" breaks the laws of domains, however, if you bring the x term inside the radical, then x=0 is part of the domain

Comment: Depends on the domain and codomain of $f$.

Comment: Even the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ is not real, so if $f$ is defined as a real function then it is undefined at $0$.

Comment: @imranfat I tend to agree with you. I was shocked to find a similar function defined to equal $0$ in Leithold's textbook.

Comment: Samrat: I disagree with you.  I would argue that if you allow $f$ to be complex-valued then the limit equals zero, which is real.

Comment: @AhmedAli On a side note here, this example clearly illustrates one has to be careful with "factoring out" an x from the square root. It does change the domain of the resulting function in this case. Had the "x" been inside, a single point (0,0) would be part of the domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ it's a real function than its domain is $x\ge1$, which doesn't include $0$, so $f(0)$ is not defined

Comment: Do you mean $x\ge 1$? The case $x=1$ is perfectly defined.

Comment: yes, of course, thanks for catching this mistake!